# Mips pc-relative address

Tags: mips, memory-address

Try to study Mips from the book Computer organization and design by David A Patterson. 4th edition.
However for one of the question regarding PC-Relative Address, I get confuse,
Question is:
Current PC is `0x00000600`, can you use a single batch instruction to get to the PC address as

> a) 1010 1101 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 
>   b) 1111 1111 1111
>   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

From the answer is for the current PC the range is:

`0X0604 + 0x1FFFC = 0x0002 0600` to `0x0604 - 0x20000 = 0xFFFE`

How do they get the 0x1FFFC and 0X20000 ?

Please help, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The Branch instructions in the MIPS architecture lets you specify a 16 bit 2s complement offset which is shifted to the left by two bits to make a 18 bit PC offset (since the instructions have to be byte aligned the lowest 2 bits always have to be a zero) and is then added or subtracted from the PC.

Now if you would take the maximum PC offset value you can add to the PC (so that you end up adding to the PC using 2s complement) with the shifting considered it would be 00000000000000011111111111111100 or 0x1FFFC.

And if you take the maximum PC offset Value you can subtract to the PC (so that you end up subtracting to the PC using 2s complement) with the shifting considered it would be 00000000000000100000000000000000 or 0x20000.

Thus if you have a PC value and you want to know what the range of addresses it can jump to, you just need to find the maximum value and the minimum value which is PC + 0x1FFFC and PC - 0x20000 respectively.

Feel free to ask any questions if you are confused about anything.

Comment: I guess my confuse is using 16bits shift to left 2 bits position, it should give me 18 bits instead 17bits 0x1FFFC, is the 18bit the sign bit? (so it is hidden in this case).
Also can you show me how the step to get the: 0x0604 - 0x20000 = 0xFFFE, no matter how I try I still not get the right answer

thanks

Comment: It does give you 18 bits. Since it uses the 2s complement method of repersenting numbers that means that there is 17 bits for addition and subtraction. The steps required for getting that equation is such: PC (Pc of the instuction that follows the.branch, that is the always the PC used in realitive addresing) - 0x20000 (this is always the maximum amount you can subtract from the PC) = Bl (the PC value if you subtract the maximum amount you can from the PC)

Comment: Also you may find this resource useful. It explains why it is shifted two to the left and the formula to calculate the range. http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addr.html

Comment: Ok I understand the 18 bits now, thanks. But... I still stuck in the 0x604 - 0x20000 = FFFE, I try to use two's complement but still not come up FFFE, can you show?   Thanks

Comment: Actually that calculation is flawed, it should be 0x604 - 0x20000 = 0xFFFE0604.

Also remember that this is 32 bit addition since the PC is 32 bit. The offset is sign-extended so that it is 32 bits too.